# Update specific field in ElasticSearch with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to update specific fields in ElasticSearch using Spark? I've been looking around everywhere and I can't find any answer to this. My script is written in Scala and I just can't seem to find any other way other than as a query to update data fields. As an example, I have this data:

```
"source" : {
    "id" : 1
    "name" : "John"
    "location" : "Los Angeles, CA"
}
```

Now I want to just change the location to New York so it looks like this:

```
"source" : {
    "id" : 1
    "name" : "John"
    "location" : "New York, NY"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way I used till now to update a specific record in Elastic using Spark is by setting option `es.mapping.id` which let's you specify which field from the record is going to be used as ID to mach against existing record and to decide if it's a new record or update of the existing one. So what you would need to do is to get the ID of existing record, update and then set the ID into a field which is going to be defined in `es.mapping.id`.

But I'm pretty sure there is other way also, I used this one because I needed to use `saveJsonToEs`, but `saveToEsWithMeta` should let you define record ID in some other way and probably more directly, without an additional field, try to google examples.